# com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.1.0 dependency is not working, even with aar file as well

Tags: android, google-api, google-pay

After adding com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.1.0 getting the below error

Failed to transform play-services-wallet-19.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}

Same issue persits if using aar file

[Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8hMi.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated the question with screenshot

Comment: Maybe this was a temporary issue? The artifact name is correct. See: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=play-services-wallet#com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.1.0

Comment: No, with the latest version also it's throwing same error